Will a rocket rotate on any axis if there's a horizontal direction force acting below the center of mass of rocket?
Let a rocket is present in space very far away from any celestial body. There's a horizontal thrust acting on the rocket below the center of mass of the rocket, the small particles are launching perpendicular to the surface just like the rockets of SpaceX during landing to adjust it's position on landing site.

Will this rocket rotate a bit on the center of mass or any other axis due to inertia of upper part of the rocket or there will be only translation motion in the horizontal direction?

No, but as far I know airplane have two opposite forces lift force due to air and weight which causes it to bend a bit. But in my question there is only one force

My apologies, I was reading the question as if the rocket was moving upwards and whether side forces played a role (which is what turbulence in an airplane is).

If you have a computer capable of running it, try building a rocket that does this in Kerbal Space Program. Its physics model does this sort of thing quite well.

This question can be answered with a rigid body assumption.  For a rigid body, it is always possible to replace a force which does not go through the Center of Mass(COM) with an equal force applied through the COM and a torque.  This new force simply applies translation, and the torque can be handled independently of the translation.  This force and torque is sometimes called a resultant force, although the term may be a bit confusing because its not just a "force" but a force and an associated torque.
How much it rotates depends on how much torque is applied and the moment of inertia about the rotational axis.  Different geometries will change the moment of inertia, and thus change the magnitude of the angular acceleration caused by any given torque.
If for some reason the rocket was not rigid, a different effect might take place.  As an extreme, consider the sinky dog child's toy.  If you pushed on the rear with some force, the rear would translate (and maybe rotate, depending on where you pushed), but the slinky would transmit very little of that to the front half of the dog.
Real SpaceX rockets at the time this question was written use vectored thrust, which let them fire the rocket not just straight down, but fire them at a slight angle to make adjustments.  This angled force could be decomposed into a problem similar to the problem you describe in the question: a downward thrust in-line with the COM (pure translation upwards) and a lateral force applied at the bottom of the rocket.  I would expect that at least one SpaceX engineer had to consider that the rocket flexes with that lateral force.  If you asked on the Space Exploration stack exchange, you might be able to find someone who knows whether that effect was significant, or if it could simply be ignored for practical calculations (or they might be able to provide similar for some NASA rocket, whose documents are often public domain and easy to cite).

Also, I think there will be translation motion on a circular path if there would not be any control system inside the rocket. Here's what I have found there link, thanks!

If the sum of your forces is a constant magnitude force that is always at right angles to your motion, then you will indeed get circular motion.  I believe that is what you intended when you drew the picture, so it should line up.  Another example of such circular motion is a circular orbit, where the force is caused by gravity rather than a thruster.
